# Facebook oauth unified scoped id across apps in same business

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

I have two facebook apps in the same business. 
I want to get same scoped ids for both apps when users are logging in (because I use the same database).
I've read the facebook upgrade guide, but I don't get how to use the token_for_business to get same id when the user is logged.
Graph api returns different tokens for business for every app (which is strange).

The only useful thing so far is the /me/ids_for_business call to get list of the user scoped IDs for every busines..but it only returns them if they were logged at least 1 time..

My second app is new and if user logs in to it (without logging in to the first app) I can't get his first app ID to store and use it.

Thanks

Comment: You will not get the same app-scoped user id – those will still be different for the same user in both apps. The `token_for_business` is the value that will uniquely identify the same user across all apps associated with the same business – so you need to store that as well. (And of course `/me/ids_for_business` only gives the app-scoped id for apps the user has already logged in to – otherwise, you are not supposed to have an app-scoped id for that app for a user.)

Comment: Yes, but that is too bad..my hope was to have the scoped id per business, not per app..this new oauth2 has so many limitations

Comment: This has nothing to do with OAuth2, it's the limitation/design of the Graph API

Answer (score 0):

There will always be differend **app-scoped** user ids per app. That's the whole purpose of them.

Have you followed the steps at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/business-manager#create-business and/or
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/business-manager#update-business

If so, according to the docs, the field `token_for_business` of the user should contain

> A token that is the same across a business's apps. Access to this token requires that the person be logged into your app. This token will change if the business owning the app changes

Comment: I did this already, but is not what I'm looking for. I wanted simple way to have user scoped id per the business, not per the application and unify their accounts in my system. Thanks anyway

Comment: Well, as you learned, this is not possible. Why don't you use the `token_for_business` instead? I should fulfill your use case as far as I understood. @CBroe mentioned that as well.